# Javascript use loops only to display arrays of a data (Not all data arrays)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I have some HTML code that I want to put data (API) in the HTML code using loops.

Each **id** is **Product** and each **product** has **layers** and each **layer** has some **options**.

My data like this (API):

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": null,
  "price": 0,
  "layers": [

  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Product Name 2",
  "price": 147,
  "layers": [
    {
      "name": "Layer One for prodct 2",
      "options": [
                    {
          "image": "image-layer-00.jpg",
          "hex": "EFEFEF"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Layer Two for product 2",
      "options": [
        {
          "image": "image-layer-11.jpg",
          "hex": "FFF"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Product Number 3",
  "price": 50,
  "layers": [
    {
      "name": "Layer One for Product 3",
      "options": [
        {
          "image": "image-layer1.jpg",
          "hex": "000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Layer Two for Product 3",
      "options": [
        {
          "image": "image-layer2.jpg",
          "hex": "fff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Layer Three for Product 3",
      "options": [
        {
          "image": "image-layer3.jpg",
          "hex": "3A3A3A"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I've used the loop to display the data list and its layers as well as the options. (javascript code in below)

But the problem with this is that my code shows all the layers of all products(ids). In other words, product layers number one, product number two, product number three ...

I want to display only the product layers selected, not all of them. (for example, if product 3 was selected, so show layers and options of product 3, not other products' layers and options.)

```
function selectModel() {

// This loop create Products List
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    $('.list').append('<li data-value="/' + "URL" + '" class="option">' + data[i].name + ' - ' + data[i].price + '$' + '</li>');

    // This loop create Products Layers
    for (k = 0; k < data[i].layers.length; k++) {

        var layersName = data[i].layers[k].name;

        var layersListCode = `<div class="head-title" id="part-${k}">
        <h3 id="title-${k}">${k}) ${layersName}:</h3>
        <div class="colors" attr-number="${k}"> </div> </div>`;

        document.getElementById("product-layers").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", layersListCode);

        // This loop create Options of Layer
        for (j = 0; j < data[i].layers[k].options.length; j++) {

            var optionHex = data[i].layers[k].options[j].hex;

            var optionsListCode = `
            <div>
            <input type="radio" data-image="blue-0" id="blue-0" name="blue-0" value="blue-0">
            <label for="blue-0"><span style="background-color: #${optionHex}"></span></label>
            </div>`;

            document.querySelector(".colors").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", optionsListCode);

        }
    }
}
```

I put the sample HTML code above to make it easier to see:

```html
<!--- Product List -->
<ul class="list">
    <li data-value="/URL" class="option">null - 0$ </li>
    <li data-value="/URL" class="option">Product Name 2 - 147$</li>
    <li data-value="/URL" class="option selected">Product Number 3 - 50$</li>
</ul>


<div id="product-layers">

    <!-- Layers-->
    <div class="head-title" id="part-1">
        <h3 id="title-1">1) Null </h3>
        <div class="colors" attr-number="1">
            <!---  Options -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Layers-->
    <div class="head-title" id="part-2">
        <h3 id="title-2">2) Product Name 2 </h3>
        <div class="colors" attr-number="2">
            <!---  Options -->
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data-image="blue-2" id="blue-2" name="blue-2" value="blue-2">
                <label for="blue-2"><span style="background-color: #EFEFEF"></span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data-image="blue-2" id="blue-2" name="blue-2" value="blue-2">
                <label for="blue-2"><span style="background-color: #fff"></span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Layers-->
    <div class="head-title" id="part-3">
        <h3 id="title-3">3) Product Name 3 </h3>
        <div class="colors" attr-number="3">

            <!---  Options -->
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data-image="blue-3" id="blue-3" name="blue-3" value="blue-3">
                <label for="blue-3"><span style="background-color: #000"></span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data-image="blue-3" id="blue-3" name="blue-3" value="blue-3">
                <label for="blue-3"><span style="background-color: #fff"></span></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data-image="blue-3" id="blue-3" name="blue-3" value="blue-3">
                <label for="blue-3"><span style="background-color: #3A3A3A"></span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the product supposed to be selected from?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva from ` $('.list')` part. first loop in javascript code and I add Html code too in code snippet. `<ul class="list>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you wished, your question is a bit cryptic, but here it is:

<kbd>[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/r5v68twy/)</kbd>

The idea is something like this:

1. At the beginning, you render only the products as a list.
2. You attach a `click` handler to let the user select one of those.
3. On selection, you iterate over the layers of the selected product, and render them as you wish (I've used your example code, though that was not extremely clear either);

---

```
function select(productIdx) {
  var product = data[productIdx];
  var options = product.layers
    .map(layer => layer.options[0])
    .map((layer, i) => {
        console.log(layer);
      return (`
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="blue-${i}" name="blue-${i}" value="blue-${i}">
          <label for="blue-${i}">
            <span style="background-color: #${layer.hex}">Label text</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      `);
    });

  $("#app .selected-product").html(`
    <h3>${product.name}</h3>
    <ul class="options">
      ${options}
    </ul>
  `);
}

jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  $("#app .list").append(() => {
    return data.map((product) => {
      return (`
        <li data-value="/URL" class="option">${product.name} - ${product.price}$</li>
      `)
    });
  });

  $("li.option").on("click", function() {
    $("li.option").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    select( $(this).index() );
  });
});
```

All in all, as a personal suggestion, I don't think you should use jQuery for this, but try some better library or framework to handle such cases. Believe me, it will save you time and pain.

Another suggestion that you can see used extensively in my code, is to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make your code more readable and easier to reason with.